# numeric range data type postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a strange situation in the desing of my DB. I have the case that the type of value of a field can be a normal integer or a number between a range. I explain myself with a example:

the column age can be a number (18) or a range between (18-30). How I can represent this with postgresql?

Thx!

Comment: Postgres has a built-in [integer range type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html)

Comment: Also a built-in `numrange` (for `numeric` ranges), or [you can create additional range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DEFINING).

Answer (score 3):

An integer [range](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) can represent both a single integer value and a range. The single value:

```
select int4range(18,18,'[]');
 int4range 
-----------
 [18,19)
```

The `")"` in the result above means exclusive.

The range:

```
select int4range(18,30,'[]');
 int4range 
-----------
 [18,31)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple different ways to do this.

1. Store a VARCHAR
2. Store two values lower bound and upper bound
3. If there are only a select set of ranges you can create a lookup table for that set and store a foreign key to that lookup table.

Comment: ah great!! Thx!! I was thinking in the first option :) But the third one is more what I need! Super

Answer (score 1):

You can make a bigger number, for example `18 x 1000 + 0 = 18000` for 18 and `18 x 1000 + 30 = 18030` for (18, 30).

When you retrieve it, you do `first = round(number/1000)` for the first number and `second = number - first` for the second number.

You can also store them as a point http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6730.